# Getting the cognitive-services-speech-sdk/quickstart/javascript/browser/text-to-speech/index.html without the startSpeakTextAsyncButton

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech, event-listener

The cognitive-services-speech-sdk/quickstart/javascript/browser/text-to-speech/index.html
is a usable code snippet that I would like to incorporate into a PHP program. But I would
like to do it without having to press the startSpeakTextAsyncButton every time I want to
use the TTS function. Instead, I would like to call the function directly as is done in
the Python code snippet published on the same site. However, when I disable the
startSpeakTextAsyncButton the JavaScript function ceases to work. The first section is the
original code, which works just fine. Following that is my rewrite of the code without the
startSpeakTextAsyncButton like this. I'm sorry, but I can't post these separately because
the editor does not like the code to be separated into two different parts.
The rewrite also runs fine and returns a "synthesis finished" message saying the code was
successful; however, my rewrite did not produce a TTS speech output, whereas the original
code did. I have debugged it, but can't find what is missing.

```
var phraseDiv;
var resultDiv;
var startSpeakTextAsyncButton;

// subscription key and region for speech services.
var subscriptionKey, serviceRegion;
var SpeechSDK;
var synthesizer;

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  startSpeakTextAsyncButton = document.getElementById("startSpeakTextAsyncButton");
  subscriptionKey = document.getElementById("subscriptionKey");
  serviceRegion = document.getElementById("serviceRegion");
  phraseDiv = document.getElementById("phraseDiv");
  resultDiv = document.getElementById("resultDiv");

  startSpeakTextAsyncButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = true;
    phraseDiv.innerHTML = "";

    if (subscriptionKey.value === "" || subscriptionKey.value === "subscription") {
      alert("Please enter your Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech subscription key!");
      startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
      return;
    }
    var speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey.value, serviceRegion.value);

    synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);

    let inputText = phraseDiv.value;
    synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
      inputText,
      function (result) {
        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
        if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
          resultDiv.innerHTML += "synthesis finished for [" + inputText + "].\n";
        } else if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.Canceled) {
          resultDiv.innerHTML += "synthesis failed. Error detail: " + result.errorDetails + "\n";
        }
        window.console.log(result);
        synthesizer.close();
        synthesizer = undefined;
      },
      function (err) {
        startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;
        resultDiv.innerHTML += "Error: ";
        resultDiv.innerHTML += err;
        resultDiv.innerHTML += "\n";
        window.console.log(err);

        synthesizer.close();
        synthesizer = undefined;
    });
  });

  if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {
    SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;
    startSpeakTextAsyncButton.disabled = false;

    document.getElementById('content').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('warning').style.display = 'none';

    // in case we have a function for getting an authorization token, call it.
    if (typeof RequestAuthorizationToken === "function") {
        RequestAuthorizationToken();
    }
  }
});  

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
var subscriptionKey = document.querySelector("#subscriptionKey");
var serviceRegion = document.querySelector("#serviceRegion");
var phraseDiv = document.querySelector("#phraseDiv");
var resultDiv = document.querySelector("#resultDiv");
var synthesizer;

if (subscriptionKey.value === "" || subscriptionKey.value === "subscription") {
    alert("Please enter your Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech subscription key!");
    return;
}
var speechConfig = SpeechSDK.SpeechConfig.fromSubscription(subscriptionKey.value, serviceRegion.value);
speechConfig.speechSynthesisVoiceName = "en-US-JennyNeural";

synthesizer = new SpeechSDK.SpeechSynthesizer(speechConfig);

let inputText = phraseDiv.value;
synthesizer.speakTextAsync(
    inputText,
    function (result) {
        if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.SynthesizingAudioCompleted) {
            resultDiv.innerHTML += "synthesis finished for [" + inputText + "].\n";
        } else if (result.reason === SpeechSDK.ResultReason.Canceled) {
            resultDiv.innerHTML += "synthesis failed. Error detail: " + result.errorDetails + "\n";
        }
        window.console.log(result);
        synthesizer.close();
        synthesizer = undefined;
    },
    function (err) {
        resultDiv.innerHTML += "Error: ";
        resultDiv.innerHTML += err;
        resultDiv.innerHTML += "\n";
        window.console.log(err);

        synthesizer.close();
        synthesizer = undefined;
    });

if (!!window.SpeechSDK) {
    SpeechSDK = window.SpeechSDK;

    document.querySelector('#content').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#warning').style.display = 'none';

    if (typeof RequestAuthorizationToken === "function") {
        RequestAuthorizationToken();
    }
}
});
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Please see [ask] and revise to clarify. Also take the [tour] so you know how this site works.

Comment: Why is most of that code commented out?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry about that. This is the original code pulled from the Azure website. It works fine as is;; however, I want the code to output the speech result directly

Comment: I have edited the original post and republished it. I hope that will clarify the original issue.